# Python Tkinter: get value from ttk.Combobox

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, combobox

I have the position data in the SQLite DB(employee_position). As well it's fetching the data for the position:

self.employee_position = employee_info[0][8]

However, I'm not able to insert the data. How can I insert the data into the combobox?

It does work for other fields like Entry:

```
    #Entry
    self.email_entry.insert(0, self.employee_email)
    self.email_entry.config(state = 'disabled')  

    # Position
    self.available = self.employee_position

    self.position_lbl = Label(self.centerFrame, text = 'Position:', fg = '#b3b3b3', bg = '#121212')
    self.position_lbl.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

    self.position = ttk.Combobox(self.centerFrame, values=self.available, width = 27)

    self.position.config(state = 'disabled')
    self.position.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)
```

Comment: What is the type of `self.employee_position`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
# Position

```
    self.available = [self.employee_position]
    self.position_lbl = Label(self.centerFrame, text = 'Position:', fg = '#b3b3b3', bg = '#121212')
    self.position_lbl.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

    self.position = ttk.Combobox(self.centerFrame, values=(self.available), width = 27)
    self.position.set(self.employee_position)
    self.position.config(state = 'disabled')
    self.position.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2, pady = 5)
```

Comment: I wonder why don't you just use `Label` instead of `Combobox` for `self.position` because there is only one item?